# Dovecot installation errors - cannot create regular file

Tags: dovecot

So i tried to install dovecot-common, dovecot-imapd and dovecot-pop3d. However, I keep getting these error messages:

```
Setting up dovecot-imapd (1:2.1.7-7+deb7u1) ...
Creating config file /etc/dovecot/conf.d/20-imap.conf with new version
cp: cannot create regular file `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/20-imap.conf': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing dovecot-imapd (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up dovecot-pop3d (1:2.1.7-7+deb7u1) ...

Creating config file /etc/dovecot/conf.d/20-pop3.conf with new version
cp: cannot create regular file `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/20-pop3.conf': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing dovecot-pop3d (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 dovecot-imapd
 dovecot-pop3d
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I checked the /etc/ folder but it seems like it's not even creating the /etc/dovecot folder because it just isn't there.

Please somebody help me...

Comment: Can you show the actual command you're running?  I'm curious if it's a permissions issue.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with dovecot, it's a (debian?) package system issue, which may be caused by a filesystem problem. Can you manually as root create the /etc/dovecot directory? (And you *are* running this as root?)

Comment: Are you installing dovecot the first time on this system? Or have you tried this already several times and did not purge the package but just removed it?

Comment: @wurtel Yes, I am running it as root. OK, I created the /etc/dovecot directory and the 'conf.d' directory inside of it and tried again to install the packages. There were no errors anymore. The directory contains 2 conf files now: 20-imap.conf and 20-pop3.conf. Should there be more of them or is everything OK? Thank you.

Comment: Eh, nevermind. I figured that out. :P I think it's working now. Thanks for the replies guys!

Comment: Don't leave a question hanging like this. Add an answer explaining what the problem was, even if it's embarrassing... it may help someone.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Sorry. I just had to reinstall the dovecot-core and other packages. I know, it IS embarrassing but well...

Answer (score -1):

Since the package cannot create the directory, why don't you try to create the /etc/dovecot instead ? Or eventually /etc/dovecot/conf.d/
There might be something not 100% correct in the package management so that the directories are not created. If you create them manually, at worst case scenario, it might mention that the directories are already there.

Comment: If you read the comments, you will see that the OP already did that, slightly over four months ago.